# How to make cmake use my newly installed Qt on the home folder?

Tags: compiling, qt, paths, cmake

My Qt was installed on `/home/lz/Qt5.11.2/`.

```
ls /home/lz/Qt5.11.2/5.11.2/gcc_64
bin  doc  include  lib  libexec  mkspecs  phrasebooks  plugins  qml  qtvirtualkeyboard  resources  translations
```

I tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/lz/Qt5.11.2/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib"
```

And compiled doing `make VERBOSE=1` just to see if this path was being used instead of the system ones, but it wasn't.

How do I make cmake use them?

ps: I also tried

```
lz@vm:~/orwell$ cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-isystem\ /home/lz/Qt5.11.2/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib .
```

This way it will use the include path but not the lib path

I also added the path `/home/lz/Qt5.11.2/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib` to ldconfig but it seems it linked only a few libs, not all of them:

```
/home/lz/Qt5.11.2/5.11.2/gcc_64/lib:
    libQt5QuickControls2.so.5 -> libQt5QuickControls2.so.5.11.2
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 -> libQt5OpenGL.so.5.11.2
    libQt5Purchasing.so.5 -> libQt5Purchasing.so.5.11.2
    libQt5Bluetooth.so.5 -> libQt5Bluetooth.so.5.11.2
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.26.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libQt5ScriptTools.so.5 -> libQt5ScriptTools.so.5.11.2
    libQt5DBus.so.5 -> libQt5DBus.so.5.11.2
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 -> libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5.11.2
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 -> libQt5Widgets.so.5.11.2
    libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so.5 -> libQt5MultimediaGstTools.so.5.11.2
    libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5 -> libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.11.2
    libQt5QuickTest.so.5 -> libQt5QuickTest.so.5.11.2
    libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5 -> libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.11.2
    libQt5PositioningQuick.so.5 -> libQt5PositioningQuick.so.5.11.2
    libQt5WebView.so.5 -> libQt5WebView.so.5.11.2
    libQt5Network.so.5 -> libQt5Network.so.5.11.2
    libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 -> libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.11.2
    libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so.5 -> libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so.5.11.2
    libQt5Designer.so.5 -> libQt5Designer.so.5.11.2
    ...
```

Comment: something like`-DQTROOT=/opt/Qt5.9.5/5.9/gcc_64/`

Comment: @kenn I did it and received the warning CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    QTROOT

and also it didn't compile

Comment: Have you tried following the Qt CMake Manual [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html)

Comment: There's some additional information here that might be useful, as well: [CMake: Finding Qt 5 the “Right Way”](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-finding-qt5-the-right-way/)

Comment: @steeldriver I modified the CMakeFiles to be done in the right way. And then did `cmake -DQt5_DIR=/home/lz/Qt5.11.2 .` but the problem persists

Comment: Did you start over with a clean build tree (in case any cached variables are messing things up)?

Comment: Last week I also needed to use custom QT to build a project. `export PATH="/opt/qt5/lib/cmake:$PATH"` did the trick.